# How can I add prefix in magento 2 Category/Product URL?

Tags: magento2

This is development url : http://www.neplyn.in/mage2/

http://www.neplyn.in/mage2/best-sellers

I want to add prefix 'collection' just before the best-sellers .

I need to the same things in the product url too.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I assume best-sellers is a category?

Comment: Yes you are right and I want to add collections just before the bes-sellers so it should be like /collections/best-sellers